# In between dates issue

Tags: t-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT QuoteReference, CreatedDate, StartDate, EndDate, Operation, OccurredAt, PerformedBy, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue
FROM Quotes, Audit  
WHERE Quotes.ID = Audit.RowId
AND PaymentReference is not null 

AND Audit.OccurredAt > Quotes.CompletedDate 
AND Quotes.CreatedDate between '2010-04-01 11:00:00.027' AND '2010-07-30 11:39:22.027'
and TableName = 'QUOTE' OR TableName = 'Quotes'
ORDER BY  Audit.OccurredAt desc
```

Despite trying a number of things, on the "quotes.createddate between..." line, I can't filter the resultset to include records with a create date between those times (1st april 2010 to 30th July 2012). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISO DATETIME FORMAT (yyyymmdd or yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm)` to sort the `date formatting issue` **if any**. Also try to `USE JOIN` tables instead of WHERE table1, table2,..

If other conditions are okay, following query should bring the records.

```
SELECT QuoteReference, CreatedDate, StartDate, EndDate, Operation, 
       OccurredAt, PerformedBy, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue

FROM Quotes JOIN Audit ON Quotes.ID = Audit.RowId --JOIN TABLES
WHERE PaymentReference is not null 
      AND Audit.OccurredAt > Quotes.CompletedDate 
      AND Quotes.CreatedDate 
            BETWEEN '20100401' AND '20100730' --Time ignored purposely for checking
      AND TableName IN  ('Quote','Quotes')
ORDER BY  Audit.OccurredAt desc
```

Comment: Problem is the query returns results AFTER the end date for created date. :(

Comment: Logic is okay, it could be something else. Can you give an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) with some data?

Comment: I have updated the query `WITHOUT TIME`, see if does any good for checking purposes?

Comment: Same issue, latest record of createddate is 2012-12-10 13:26:24.000

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle that is the best way to understand. Nothing wrong with queries.

Comment: I fixed this by removing the tablename condition (2nd from bottom line). Odd.

Answer (score 0):

Your date range is incorrect,  use:

```
between '2010-04-01 00:00:00:000' AND '2012-07-30 23:59:59:999'
```

Comment: Problem is the query returns results AFTER the end date for created date. :(

Comment: What is the end date? '2012-07-30 23:59:59:999' or '2012-07-30 00:00:00:000'

Comment: As in your answer, so 2012-07-30 23:59:59:999